# Stop a person from entering my database and make changes

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

This one is probably very easy for most of you to answer and resolve, but not me... I could use some help and guidance.

Someone had got access to my site, and now he keeps deleting tables from the sites's mysql database, I've changed the password for Cpanel login and The database username as well. But somehow he's still able to access it. I put back the database and he erases them again, it's going a loop. I can't seem to figure out how he's doing it and how to stop him.

I have full control of the Cpanel. Can anyone suggest anything ?

EDITED: After reading the first few comments and solutions, I realised that I'm not a newcomer but a complete naive. So, request all of you humble and amazing folks to put it a little more effort and make it easier for me to follow, as I'm not a SQL person. Thank a ton !

2nd Editing: The site is built on a Yii Framework. and the table user is being deleted most of the times.

Comment: Have you checked if your site is prone to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Comment: You could try posting your PHP code with special regards to how you handle SQL queries and inputs from your site on http://codereview.stackexchange.com . (And possibly be prepared for the *swarm* of comments on how to sanitize your inputs and do proper SQL querying. Doing a "delete all" is **very** easy to do if you are vulnerable to SQL injection.)

Comment: @AndriyM , how would one do that ? Please guide me ...

Comment: @ppeterka , so I'm should create a new thread there ?

Comment: Do NOT post application code in DBA.SE. Re-read @ppeterka comment and try there.

Comment: MichaelGreen, @ppeterka you'll need to be more clear..I still don't understand what to do ? In plain English please ...

Comment: Take a look at the ouput from `SELECT user, host, left(password, 11) FROM mysql.user;`  That will show if any logins have no password, and any logins that you don't remember making.

Comment: Error  
SQL query: Documentation  


SELECT user, host, left(password, 11) FROM mysql.user  
 LIMIT 0, 25   
MySQL said: Documentation  

#1142 - SELECT command denied to user '*username*'@'localhost' for table 'user'

Comment: I'm not able to format the comment in a proper way, so please bear with me. This is what the output i have got, @RickJames

Comment: If you can't log in as root, you won't be able to stop them, and you _may_ not be able to even see them.  You need to be root to everything.

Comment: by root, do you mean the cpanel adimn ?
Cause, i have that and the WHM as well....tell me what to do next... please...

Comment: ok, so i figured that the person is probably sending commands through the login box ( username / password), which i have disabled. and along with that, i even changed the database name. But, he's still able to down my site... any ideas ?

Comment: About the logs....there are a few entries, just before the site goes down... should i post it here, maybe anyone can read then and decode them for me ?

Answer (score 2):

So first you need check the access log on your web server. If it's SQL injection you should see probably straight URLs. You can also restore database once again, and turn on log queries, then you can see which user delete tables - [Log all queries in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql)

Comment: seems a simple way to figure it out..  please help me, with steps, not an expert. thanks